# Communication between Swing Client and Ejb container

Tags: swing, ejb, jms

i'm trying to drop all database access on my swing application thats why i created an EJB module hosted in a jboss server where i put all my database calls.

My question is : what is the best middleware  i can use to ensure effective communication between client and server without decreasing my swing application performance ?

I've seen that JMS represents a solution of my problem , but is it the best one ?

Please Help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMS is preferably used for communicating between two systems where failure or downtime of one system leads to instability (i.e providing full availablity). Also db calls will be highly transactional so JMS is not the right approach.

You can either call the ejb from your swing action class, but it is likely to add a considerable amount of boilerplate code. Another alternative will be exposing web services that will in turn call the ejb's for db access. That might give you a whole service oriented design.

If it is possible, you can move your whole swing application to Dynamic Web application, that way it will give you 'n' number of options.

Reading through J2EE basics might help you to find the solution.

Comment: Thank you @Sathyan for your reply ! i just wanna ask if your are familiar with using web services, can this technology manage the concurrent access  to my Ejb ?